# Is it possible to access the Browser local storage of another domain from the active one?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

If you use javascript and you are running in acme.com, you can set and retrieve variables with no problem at all.

But if you have SSO running in acme2.com, and it sets variables, can you retrieve those from site1.acme.com?

I cant see a way to pass the domain as a variable.

EXAMPLE if my page is page1.acme.com and I do set local.Storage("Jvariable", "value1"), then Mozilla, Chrome, and edge show the values of Jvariable, 1.

but can I set local.Stroage("Jvariable", "value1", acme2.com), and retrieve it too?

When I set local storage variables they are set on the browser in the domain of the site hosting the page. I need to access other subdomains as well.

Comment: No. Browsers do not know anything about SSO.

Comment: You could get it to work if you have access to both domains and make use of the [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) protocol. You'd still need either **(a)** both tabs open at the same time, or **(b)** an `<iframe />` of one of the pages nested in the other. Note that the page could be blank accept for the JavaScript needed to send the message. Microsoft made use of something like this in the super old Azure portal to get around limitations of cross-domain sharing by applying the check in a `setInterval()` function that polled updates.

Comment: No. For use-cases like these the variables need to be saved on a server. With the correct configuration of CORS headers both pages can access data from the same server.

Comment: Technically, it can be saved in local storage for both domains, but you need to figure out a way to get to it. I'm thinking redirect to acme2.com/auth, where variables are retrieved from local storage, then that page opens page.acme.com/get-auth?vars=[vars here], which gets the vars from query and stores them. It's it safe? Nope, but it's doable. And with the right effort it probably can be made fairly safe...

Comment: I agree server side code is cool, but we are using local storage as we have much more control over hashes....But point noted. In this case I do have both domains open in the app... so I will check it out.

Comment: We are building a cross-platform page locking platform, and thus we do in fact need local storage. with local storage I can block access to any remote site...or URL...even if there are 1M domains external.... In this case I only need local storage from 2 URLs accessible.

Comment: We were hoping that Mozilla, Chrome or Edge might have a javascript library to allow us to access Browser Side memory variables...as an admin right programatically.....as another approach.